# Understanding an integral

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

Let $P$ be a probability transition matrix on a finite space $\Omega$ with stationary distribution $\pi$. Let

$$A\subset \Omega, \text{ for } x,y\in \Omega,  Q(x,y):=\pi(x)P(x,y)$$

$$ A_u:=\{y\in\Omega| Q(A,y)\geq u\pi (y)\} \text{ where u is a uniform random number from }[0,1]$$

> Then, if $A_u\subset A$, I don't understand why the following integral is equal to its right hand side (not understanding the usage of definition of $A_u$ in the integral)?
> $$\int_{1/2}^1 \pi(A_u)du = \sum_{y\in A}\left[ \frac{Q(A,y)}{\pi(y)}-\frac{1}{2}\right]\pi(y)$$

Thanks.

Comment: Since $P$ is a probability transition matrix, are we supposed to read $P(x,y)$ as the probability $x\to y$? Is the stationary distribution of a set taken to mean the sum of the probabilities of of the elements of the set?

Comment: @AndrewShedlock Yes to both.